# Tilda references in Blazor Components not working

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor-server-side

In classic ASP.NET MVC, I typically make all references to static assets using the following pattern

```
<img width="110" height="38" src="~/images/logo/logo_light.svg" alt="...">
```

I am now trying to do the same using razor pages in a server-side rendered Blazor web app.

If I use `'~'` references in my main `_Layout.cshtml` Razor page then the functionality works as expected and the `'~'` is substituted with the root of the application.

However, if I use a `'~'` reference in a component, then the `'~'` is not recognised and it ends up in the resulting HTML and hence creates broken links.

Why does `'~'` not work in Blazor components? Is there an alternative approach that can be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `~` in Blazor - it uses root-relative urls - based on the base-path of the site.

You can remove the `~` from your example.